# ansible how is hostvars and gathered facts and facts from setup module different

Tags: ansible

What are the differences in getting values from hostvars and facts from calling setup module different in Ansible?

If I were to keep host specific values, just use hostvars to get values?
I have a long list of hosts(grouped). If I were to use hostvars to retrieve values, how can I distinguish hosts from groups?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You define host vars in your inventory prior to contacting your hosts.
You collect facts during setup phase.

Both host vars and collected facts are merged into same dictionary `hostvars`, so you can't distinguish them in runtime.

Groups are used just to logically group hosts and nothing more, all group variables are merged into same `hostvars` dictionary for every host in a group, so you can't distinguish what is group var and and what is host var.

All this variables/fact are accessible by there name (like `{{ var_name }}`) when you in the current host context, or via `hostvars['other_host']['var_name']` from other hosts' context.